# Reading emails with IMAP while displaying progress

Tags: php, mysql, imap

Using IMAP, I need to read a mail account and save the message_ID into a MySQL Table while displaying the progress with "*"

My code seems to work, however it doesn't produce the expected results..

section of code below :-

```
$MC = imap_check($mbox);

$result = imap_fetch_overview($mbox,"1:{$MC->Nmsgs}",0);

$count = 0;

echo "Total -  ".$MC->Nmsgs." </br>";

foreach ($result as $overview) {

    $message_id = $overview->message_id;
    $query = "INSERT INTO `$sqltable` (`message_id`) VALUES ('$message_id')";
    $results = mysql_query($query);
    $count = $count +1;
    echo "*";
    if ($count >= 80) {
    $count = 0;
    echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

The database starts updating with the results, however the total message count, and progress indicator "*" is not displayed until the process is complete..

Any advice would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Flush the output. The output of your script is buffered, and you have to explicitly ask the system to start sending it to the client while the script still runs.

Of course, you will have all the funny "details" like having to deal with what happens when your client aborts before you have saved each and every message, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to flush the output. there are two methods:

1 - turn off content buffering, to enable to push it to browser immediatly:

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();
```

2 - inside foreach, before closing } add code to send buffer to browser:

```
flush();
ob_flush();
```